# Java,как получить значение параметра аннотации?

Tags: java, рефлексия, аннотации

Есть класс помеченный аннотацией @haveArea с параметром name, как получить значение параметра.

```
    @haveArea(name = "Прямоугольник")
    public class Rectangle {
    double a;
    double b;

    public Rectangle(double a, double b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @returnArea
    void getArea() {
        System.out.println(a * b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала настроить аннотацию, чтобы она была доступна во время выполнения:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@interface haveArea {
...
}
```

А потом с помощью метода `Class.getAnnotation`:

```
haveArea annotation = Rectangle.class.getAnnotation(haveArea.class);
System.out.println(annotation.name);
```

И еще. В java есть соглашение о наименовании, согласно которому аннотации (как и классы и интерфейсы) должны начинаться с большой буквы.

Answer (score -2):

Обычно, аннотация реализуется приблизительно так:

1)Декларируется интерфейс - `haveArea`

2)Далее пишется класс который реализует этот интерфейс, типа `class MyHaveArea implements haveArea` в рамках которого и собственно пишется сам код аннотации, причем параметры аннотации равны полям интерфейса, исходя из этого пишем код типа:

```
Rectangle rectangle; //сам объект
Class clazz = rectangle.getClass(); //класс объекта
Annotation[] annotations = clazz.getAnnotations(); //список аннотаций класса

for(Annotation annotation : annotations) {
    //annotation теперь указывает на интерфейс аннотации `haveArea`
    //список полей интерфейса
    Field[] fields = annotation.getDeclaredFields(); 
    for (Field field : fields) {
       if (field.getName().compareTo("name")==0) //поле с именем name
          System.out.println("name = " + field.get(rectangle).toString());
    }
}
```

Пысы: не проверял, просто как идею кинул.

Comment: Зачем нужен класс `MyHaveArea` и какой там будет `код аннотации`?

Comment: `MyHaveArea` и правда не нужен. Я его привел только для иллюстрации - одному богу ведомо какой там код...